# use socket to write contents read from nfq -- bind to specific ip address fails

Tags: c, sockets, networking, bind

Intention: extract the source ip from icmp packet and post a dummy http request using source ip.

I am writing a sample program to get icmp packet. This part can be done using nfq_create_queue related api's. I get the IP header and identify protocol as ICMP and extracted the IP (verdict for icmp packet is set to drop).

Now, I am creating sample query (http v1.1, some url say http://www.stackoverflow.com). To post the query, I create TCP client socket and bind to extracted IP. I send the query using the client socket where a Server reads its properly.

I find issue in binding:-
bind fails with invalid argument. ( verified with gdb, all values for bind is proper).
 if I dont have bind to extracted ip, with 127.0.0.1 I am able to see messages at server end.

Observation:-
The fd value from nfq_handle is same as TCP server on the other side.

Can anyone pls explain, is my intention achievable using nfq and socket?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do here, or what you mean by 'extracted IP', but you can only bind to a local IP address.

Comment: I want to retain the IP of traffic originating. Say for example Ihave host A and host B. Host B receives Host A traffic. Received traffic is taken via NFQ, extract source ip from packet ( here it will be host A IP). Then bind a socket with host A ip and send http dummy request to another application in Host B. If I dont do binding, the listener does not know where the traffic is coming from. He will get it as 127.0.0.1

Comment: You cannot do this. You can't bind a socket on host B to host A. It is impossible. There is soething seriously wrong with your requirement, or your understanding of TCP primitives.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. is there any way to do it? One possible way is to encapsulate original packet ip as payload, and receiver has to retrieve it.

Comment: Hi EJP, will this work for me?  setsockopt with "IP_TRANSPARENT" [link] http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip